# webmaster tools says robots.txt unreachable, but it exists

Tags: robots.txt

I am having real problems with a new website, which I'm trying to configure in google webmaster tools. I keep getting the message 'Unreachable robots.txt' and google says it can't crawl my site as it can't reach the robots.txt file.

As you will see, the file exists and I have checked the server headers and they are returning status 200 for the file.

http:// www . top5beauty.co.uk / robots.txt (without the spaces)

Oddly, when I fetch http:// top5beauty.co.uk / robots.txt (no www) it finds it no problem, even though this actually redirects to www

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: And if you fetch www.top5beauty.co.uk/robots.txt what you get?

the fetch for non www is fine because google gets 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt can take up to 2 days to fetch, if you have just created the file, you need to wait :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do a "Fetch as Googlebot" test in your Webmaster tools to instantly see if any page/URL/file is reachable
2. In you've set a "Disallow:" rule which blocks all access. If you want to be indexed, you should remove it ASAP.
3. To learn more about robot.txt you should visit [this official documentation](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) and also, due to recent changes in Googlebot methods I would recommend reading a recent [Googlebot post](http://www.incapsula.com/the-incapsula-blog/item/395-new-snippet-puts-googlebot-in-the-spotlight) I`ve wrote on the subject.

BTW: As much as I like my post, I still think you should read Google's documentation 1st as it deal with most basic question :)

Cheers